# Android Studio - Views becomes grey in design view

Tags: android

[image]

Why are those 5 views grey? Should I be worried about it?

Comment: `Should I be worried about it?` run your app and see. i think it's just an indication from the editor to show you some padding or margin for these views or something like that

Comment: I run my app and I got no errors. I thought those are grey are because of warnings or something like that. Or maybe it's like what you said. The padding or margin stuff.

Comment: Should I be worried about it? No ;)

Comment: it's not a warning, although you clearly have numerous other warnings for this layout already